# TinyMCE Cakephp 1.3.14

Tags: php, cakephp, tinymce

Hi I triying to work with **TinyMCE version 3.4.9** in **Cakephp 1.3.14** i see many tutorials and some plugins but it dont work anyone can give some hand to puth this to work i appreciate it very much ^_^

Comment: Use the javascript API and Cake won't go into the way.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Post some code so we can analyze.

Comment: Have you tried using this: https://github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the tinyMCE directory with all of it contents in the javascript directory of cakePHP, located in the webroot (app/webroot/js).

Now, include tinyMCE in your layout:

```
echo $this->Html->script('tinymce/tiny_mce') . "\n";
```

After you've done this, you need to initialize tinyMCE, there are various ways of doing this, but an example would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced"
    });
</script>
```

Which you could also place in your layout. Visit the tinyMCE website for more details concerning what you could initialize.

With this code all your textarea's will turn in tinyMCE fields. Although this question is poorly formulated and lacks any research effort, I hope this will help most Googlers who come across this post.

Comment: Yes is already jejeje i found the error is problem permision the directory are there buth are no accesible for the user www i already fixed thanks

Comment: I wonder which frustrated idiot who didn't get tinyMCE to work with CakePHP, even after reading this post, negged me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js` in your layout

Comment: Yes is already jejeje i found the error is problem permision the directory are there buth are no accesible for the user www i already fixed thanks